# SQL how to retrieve the middle point between two given dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates:

`2012-10-04 12:48:56:000` and `2012-10-04 12:48:58:000`

Expected result is
`2012-10-04 12:48:57:000`

---

`2012-10-04 12:48:56:000` and `2012-10-04 12:48:56:010`

Expected result is
`2012-10-04 12:48:56:005`

(the dates are fictional, since in sql server the millisecond part DATETIME datatype is increasing by 3 )

Comment: do you mean you have 2 date columns and want to output the middle point by a select or are the 2 dates diffrent rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your own dates...

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 
          DATEDIFF(ms,'2012-10-04 12:48:56:000', '2012-10-04 12:48:58:000')/2,
         '2012-10-04 12:48:56:000')
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in postgresql with time(6) values? I'm sad and desperate and porting this exact code over to Postgres from Sql Server. I feel this comment might be appropriate in case someone finds this and are in postgres (the title doesn't say sql server which is how I ended up here) and the question gets answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711115/postgresql-to-find-midpoint-between-two-timestamps

Comment: The logic in DATEDIFF is backwards!  It threw me completely when finding out the first date provided is subtracted from the second date rather than the other way around.  So `DATEDIFF(MS, @dateA, @dateB)` really means @dateB - @dateA!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
with sample_data (start_dt, end_dt) as 
( 
   select cast('2012-10-04 12:48:56:000' as datetime), cast('2012-10-04 12:48:58:000' as datetime)
   union all
   select cast('2012-10-04 12:48:56:000' as datetime), cast('2012-10-04 12:48:56:010' as datetime)
)
select start_dt, end_dt, dateadd(millisecond, datediff(millisecond, start_dt, end_dt) / 2, start_dt)
from sample_data
```

Although the second pair doesn't compute properly. Probably because of the 3 milliseconds resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @date1 datetime;
declare @date2 datetime;

set @date1 = '2012-10-04 12:48:56:000';
set @date2 = '2012-10-04 12:48:58:000';

select DateAdd(ms, DateDiff(ms, @date1, @date2)/2, @date1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be able to do this with MySQL and MariaDB. This is what worked:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2012-10-06 12:48:58.000', INTERVAL time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF('2012-10-04 12:48:56.000', '2012-10-06 12:48:58.000'))/2 SECOND)
```

The result: 2012-10-05 12:48:57.000000

Answer (score 0):

```
-- let's day d1 and d2 are DateTime variables (d1 < d2)

-- get the differnce in milliseconds 
-- (you can change it but be careful with oveflow situations)
declare @diff integer = datediff (ms, @d1, @d2)
-- the middle is the first date + half of the difference
declare @middle DateTime = dateadd (ms, @diff / 2, @d1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (you can replace the date part depending on how accurate you want to be):

```
DateAdd(ms, DateDiff(ms, date1, date2), date1)/2
```

Comment: This cannot be correct. 1. DateAdd function, 2. You need to divide the difference by 2 and then add it to the date1

Comment: Correct, typo on my part 

DateAdd(ms, DateDiff(ms, date1, date2), date1)/2

Comment: Still answer is not correct. You need to divide the output of the datediff function by 2 and then add it to date1

Comment: there's a missing `,` and this returns `date2` (aproximated).