# MySQL how get middle point between two given times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 times value

`06:00:00` and `14:00:00`

expected result is

`10:00:00`

FYI. I want to write this into my trigger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL how to retrieve the middle point between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745414/sql-how-to-retrieve-the-middle-point-between-two-given-dates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your times to seconds, then find the middle value, and convert back to time

The middle value of two numeric values is simply `(a + b) / 2`

```
SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(time1) + TIME_TO_SEC(time2)) / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
i just relize about SEC_TO_TIME that i keep finding the solution for a day

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you can get the middle of two values using:

```
start + (end - start) / 2
```

This is quite useful when working with domains where addition is not wll defined but subtraction is.  For times (or datetimes in general), you can use:

```
select t.*,
       (time_start + interval timestampdiff(second, time_start, time_end) / 2 second) as midpoint
from (select time('04:00:00') as time_start, time('11:00:00') as time_end) t;
```

I will also note that this easily adapts to other levels of precision, as opposed to just seconds.